# AWS manage ec2 inbound/outboud rules by user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

As an administrator, I am looking for a way to allow users to manage their own inbound/outbound rules for a specific security group but disallow them from modifying the inbound/outbound rules of other security groups. Now this is possible using policies, however, the only issue with this approach is that you would have to add each employee's security group to each EC2 instance.

For instance (pun intended), if I have 20 EC2s and 50 employees, I'd need manually to add 50 * 20 security groups. That's not practical.

What is a more manageable solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm confused - if all security groups are on all EC2 instances, then any changes an employee makes to their security group would propagate to all EC2 instances. So aren't they effectively changing ingress for other employees? Shouldn't each employee just get an EC2 instance and a security group defined by CloudFormation which also creates their policy for managing the security group?

Comment: These are shared EC2 instances running the backend services. So employees as they move about need access to these instances. Only the Admin has the ability to create new instances. 
Now you could have a single security group across all instances with inbound/outbound rules for each employee. However, then the Admin must update Ip addresses for the employee if their Ip changes (since we don't want to allow write access to all employees on all EC2 instances). The employee needs the ability to change their own Ip address and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit Based on OP feedback**

Ok, so if I understand your situation correctly;

- You have N number of engineers who need to connect to backend EC2 instances within your VPC.
- You regulate traffic to/from the EC2 instances based on IP
- Engineers move around, so IP address changes. Thus, they need to be able to update with their new IP address.

I think the AWS Preferred response (What they ask on DevOps Pro cert, and claim on whitepapers) is that you set up a Bastion Host or Jumpbox. Depending on how the network connection works.

Either way, you can restrict all connections to the backend services to your Bastion host, and require engineers to first connect there and then ssh over to the other servers. That simplifies the security groups on your application instances. This obviously assumes you're using SSH, but you could do something similar with RDP I'm sure.

If you want to continue with the IP based rules, I guess that would work - just attach every security group onto the bastion host and then engineers can manage it like that.

However, there's more to security than that. Right now, you're only answering the question of "Authorization", not Authentication and you still need to consider Governance

**Authentication**

If it's only set by IP, then anyone on that IP can connect. What AWS suggests is having every engineer produce an SSH keypair. They upload their public cert to S3 and keep their private key with them. Then have CRON job run every few minutes that pulls public keys on S3 down and makes a user entry for them using that key.

This way, only people who've uploaded a public key to S3 can access your Bastion host, and then get onto a backend server.

**Governance**

You should also make sure to keep track of who's logging in, and what they're doing. Since you now have a central point of connection, you can send logs of user actions to S3 and CloudWatch. I think you can even fire off a CloudWatch event if someone performs actions they shouldn't be able to. It should be easy to tell where they are originating and where they are trying to go.

Overall, I think you should consider removing the entire IP filtering policy and get a VPN connection. It maybe costs 40~100/month but it's much more secure. If you have engineers manually setting IPs it's only a matter of time until someone messes up and a massive CIDR block is left open to the world. Also, consider the value in returned engineer time. Having to get their IP and set it in AWS is non-value adding work

---

**Initial Post**

So, I'm not really sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. But I'm guessing you want to give each employee a unique environment which they can change as they wish. You have a couple of options for this

**CloudFormation - The best option, IMO**
Build a master CloudFormation template which is used to build all the pieces you need:

- EC2 Instance
- Security Group
- Policy

Make sure it has a parameter for the IAM role of the user, which will be tied to the policy.

Next, register the stack as an App with Service Catalog. Give your IAM users the ability to launch the App, and have it provide their IAM role as the parameter. That should give them their instance and the ability to edit the security group (Assuming the policy is set up correctly)

**Launch Configuration. Hacky, but might work**

1. Make a security group for each employee and a policy for each of them.
2. Define a launch configuration for autoscaling groups.
3. Then, launch all your EC2 instances using the Launch Configuration and provide all the security groups in the configuration.
4. Scale out the EC2 instances to however many you need. Each Security Group will be applied to each EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed post! So with our current setup we are in fact using VPN and a bastion box but these are only accessible to authorized Ip addresses. Thus, we want engineers to be able to set Ips themselves. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you're using a bastion - then why do you need all the servers to have the security groups on them that let engineers set IP? That seems like a security concern. Just put one SG on the bastion for each engineer. And everything in your network can allow communication via the bastion. Otherwise, use the Launch Configuration with AutoScaling Groups like I mentioned.

Comment: But overall - I think setting IPs manually just opens you to human error. Using private/public keys is plenty secure. I know many Government agencies that use that exact method. Otherwise, you should automate this process of IP setting. Write a script that uses the AWS CLI to update CFN stacks with new IPs. Make sure it calls the AWS MFA endpoint for a token as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS Client VPN.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html

User with VPN client installed on their devices can vpn from any public network to the vpc and can access the resources securely. There won't be any need to maintain and update Security Group for each user.